# How to use existing any mobile network gateway to send sms through asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, api, sms-gateway

I'm trying to develop an application in asp.net with messaging feature using existing any mobile network gateway. Is it possible to use gateway and send messages free through application using gateway. Or any other API would be perfect. Seeking response...

Comment: which api gateway are you using ?

Comment: Different gateways use different APIs. SO isn't a product recommendation site - questions asking for product recommendations are out of scope and closed. Are you asking about a specific gateway? Do you have a specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

way2sms  gateway to send sms through asp.net needed via webservice

```
string mbno, mseg, ckuser, ckpass;
private HttpWebRequest req;
private CookieContainer cookieCntr;
private string strNewValue;
public static string responseee;
private HttpWebResponse response;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   ckuser = "Yourusername";
   ckpass = "YourPassword";

   try
   {
     this.req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wwwd.way2sms.com/auth.cl");

     this.req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
     this.req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
     this.req.Method = "POST";
     this.req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     this.strNewValue = "username=" + ckuser + "&password=" + ckpass;
     this.req.ContentLength = this.strNewValue.Length;
     StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(this.req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
     writer.Write(this.strNewValue);
     writer.Close();
     this.response = (HttpWebResponse)this.req.GetResponse();
     this.cookieCntr = this.req.CookieContainer;
     this.response.Close();
     this.req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wwwd.way2sms.com//jsp/InstantSMS.jsp?val=0");
     this.req.CookieContainer = this.cookieCntr;
     this.req.Method = "GET";
     this.response = (HttpWebResponse)this.req.GetResponse();
     responseee = new StreamReader(this.response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
     int index = Regex.Match(responseee, "custf").Index;
     responseee = responseee.Substring(index, 0x12);
     responseee = responseee.Replace("\"", "").Replace(">", "").Trim();
     this.response.Close();

     pnlsend.Visible = true;
     lblErrormsg.Text = "connected";
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
     lblErrormsg.Text = "Error connecting to the server...";
   }
   }




protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   mbno = txtTo.Text;//To mobile number
   mseg = txtMessage.Text;//Message

   if ((mbno != "") && (mseg != ""))
   {
     try
     {
     this.req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wwwd.way2sms.com//FirstServletsms?custid=");
     this.req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
     this.req.CookieContainer = this.cookieCntr;
     this.req.Method = "POST";
     this.req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     this.strNewValue = "custid=undefined&HiddenAction=instantsms&Action=" + responseee + "&login=&pass=&MobNo=" + this.mbno + "&textArea=" + this.mseg;

     string msg = this.mseg;
     string mbeno = this.mbno;

     this.req.ContentLength = this.strNewValue.Length;
     StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(this.req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
     writer.Write(this.strNewValue);
     writer.Close();
     this.response = (HttpWebResponse)this.req.GetResponse();

     this.response.Close();
     lblErrormsg.Text = "Message Sent..... " + mbeno + ": " + msg;
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
     lblErrormsg.Text="Error Sending msg....check your connection...";
     }
   }
   else
   {
     lblErrormsg.Text = "Mob no or msg missing";
   }
   }
 - Above code will connect your account to way2sms please chnage code with your username and password
```

Comment: Posting without any explanation isn't very helpful, especially when describing an API or a multi-step process. At least you should explain some unusual choices eg using raw HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient or even WebClient, hardcoding the ASCII encoding *without* the corresponding HTTP header, the unusual error handling. As it is, it's unclear what this code does, although it's clear it needs some cleanup

Comment: Other serious issues - using fields instead of local variables, not disposing the request/response/reader objects esp. when exceptions occur